# How to split the pathnames and print each of them by choice?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this code, I want to split the paths. But when I used the `split` function, the paths are arranged in a list and it didn't split them. I don't know why?

**printing hello**

```
['/home/runner/TestP1/folder1', '']
['/home/runner/TestP1/folder1/sub', '']
['/home/runner/TestP1/folder2', '']
```

**printing hello[1]**

```
No result. Nothing shows up
```

**Desired output print(hello[1])**

```
/home/runner/TestP1/folder1/sub
```

**Code**

```
import os
 
def listdirs(rootdir):
    for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
        d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            e = d + ","
            print(e)
            # hello = e.split(",")
            # print(hello[1])
            listdirs(d)
        
 
rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
listdirs(rootdir)
```

Comment: I can't tell what you want.  Please show us the results you are trying to get, and we'll show you where you went wrong.  Your code doesn't make much sense; you append a single comma to each path name, then try to split it

Comment: Since `,` is your delimiter, and your `e` has had a `,` post-pended to it, `split()` will consider that to be 2-elements.  Just like in a csv file with 10 columns, and say the first row was all blanks, you would expect to find 9 commas, i.e. `,,,,,,,,,`

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: @HetalThaker I updated the code. You can see the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below solution:

```
import os
 
dirs = []
def listdirs(rootdir):
    for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
        d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            dirs.append(d)
            listdirs(d)
    
        
 
rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
listdirs(rootdir)
print(dirs[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `e` has had a `,` post-pended to it, so `split()` will split that to a list of size `2`.

Just like in a csv file with `10` columns, and say the first row was all blanks, you would expect to find one row in the csv file consisting of `9` commas, i.e. `,,,,,,,,,`import os

This will print all directories, recursively.

```
def listdirs(rootdir):
    for file in os.listdir(rootdir):
        d = os.path.join(rootdir, file)
        if os.path.isdir(d):
            print(d)
            listdirs(d)
        
 
rootdir = '/home/runner/TestP1'
listdirs(rootdir)
```